# Index Out of Rnage in finding ways for binary maze

Tags: python

Basically, I want to find the number of unique paths on the maze, but however, I've tried this code and it's working for my first matrix of the binary maze, however, it only identifies 1 unique path, however, the answer should be 2 because, on the maze[3][0], it could take a new unique path using the "right-down" choice rather than going to maze[4][0] and taking "right" choice.

```
# Check if cell (x, y) is valid or not
```

def isValidCell(x, y, N, M):
return not (x < 0 or y < 0 or x >= N or y >= M)

def countPaths(maze, i, j, dest, visited):

```
# `N × M` matrix
N = len(maze)
M = len(maze[0])

# if destination (x, y) is found, return 1
if (i, j) == dest:
    return 1

# stores number of unique paths from source to destination
count = 0

# mark the current cell as visited
visited[i][j] = True

# if the current cell is a valid and open cell
if isValidCell(i, j, N, M) and maze[i][j] == 1:
    
    print(i)
    # go down (i, j) ——> (i + 1, j)
    if i + 1 < N and not visited[i + 1][j]:
        print("down")
        count += countPaths(maze, i + 1, j, dest, visited)
        
        # go up (i, j) ——> (i - 1, j)
    elif i - 1 >= 0 and not visited[i - 1][j]:
        print("up")
        count += countPaths(maze, i - 1, j, dest, visited)
        
        # go right (i, j) ——> (i, j + 1)
    elif j + 1 < M and not visited[i][j + 1]:
        print("right")
        count += countPaths(maze, i, j + 1, dest, visited)

    # go right-down (diagonal) (i, j) ——> (i + 1, j + 1)
    elif j + 1 < M and i + 1 < N and not visited[i + 1][j + 1]:
        print("right down")
        count += countPaths(maze, i + 1, j + 1, dest, visited)

    
# backtrack from the current cell and remove it from the current path
visited[i][j] = False

return count
```

def findCount(maze, src, dest):

```
# get source cell (i, j)
i, j = src

# get destination cell (x, y)
x, y = dest

# base case: invalid input
if not maze or not len(maze) or not maze[i][j] or not maze[x][y]:
    return 0

# `N × M` matrix
N = len(maze)
M = len(maze[0])

print(M)
# 2D matrix to keep track of cells involved in the current path
visited = [[False for k in range(M)] for l in range(N)]

# start from source cell (i, j)
return countPaths(maze, i, j, dest, visited)
```

if **name** == '**main**':

```
maze = [
    [1, 0], 
    [1, 0], 
    [1, 0], 
    [1, 0], 
    [1, 1] 
]

# source cell
src = (0, 0)

# destination cell
dest = (4, 1)

print("The total number of unique paths are", findCount(maze, src, dest))
```

Answer (score 0):

The code assumes a square matrix

```
# `N × N` matrix
N = len(maze)
```

You are feeding it a rectangular matrix `maze =`  15x5 (didn't count the lines, guesstimated)

Comment: I already change the "N" become 2 seperate which are N for row and M for col, but it still gives the error.

Comment: Do you know how scary it would be if I was able to help you? But rest assured, I am unable to read your mind and can't fix code you aren't showing.

Comment: Sorry, I have already changed the code to the newer version, and so if you could help, it is very useful for me, thank you.